# Converting a project from .NET5 to .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, nuget, .net-4.8, .net-5

Long story, summarized...
I started working on a solution creating many projects (like class libraries) for the solution.  Then I ended up needing to use a third-party SDK for something I had an expensive license for.  Come to find out, that third-party SDK only supported `.NET Framework`.

Because my solution was based in `.NET 5/Core` and the SDK in `.NET Framework` I had a big issue.  They can not exist in the same environment and reference each other.  So, on to biting the bullet and spending hours converting all my projects to `.NET Framework 4.8` while singing a neverending song of curse words...

### The Issue

My first class library I'm trying to convert from `.NET5` to `.NET 4.8` happens to have a Nuget package installed.  That Nuget is `Newtonsoft.Json Version="12.0.3"` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json).

After changing the framework in the project file, VSCode is telling me the Newtonsoft namespace can not be found.  This makes me think that the Nuget I have installed is not compatible with .NET Framework 4.8.

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json is the most popular Nuget library of all time. Of course it supports .NET Framework. Yep, even version 12.0.3 supports it. If you ever have a question about framework support, [check FuGet](https://www.fuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json).

Comment: Thanks for the link @mason!  I'm guessing you were the downvote too.  I'll more than likely delete the question and submit a new one asking about the errors I see in my project after switching to net48 framework.

Comment: Actually, nevermind.  Looks like it was just another great OmniSharp issue.  It seems to have flipped out when I changed the framework (not that I really blame it...  too much).  After a VSCode restart (or I could have restarted OmniSharp), it now no longer shows the Newtonsoft namespace not being found.

Comment: Using VS Code to develop .NET Framework apps is not going to be a pleasant experience. You'll probably continue to run into problems. Visual Studio will be your best bet, or perhaps Rider.

Comment: I decided to leave the question posted with an answer in hopes it helps someone else in the same situation.

Comment: I actually just jumped on the VSCode wagon.  It's not that bad once you figure out where all the potholes are in the dark room.  I came from VS 2019.  I have heard about Rider though, think I will try that out soon.

Comment: I'm not saying VS Code is bad. It's great. The issue is that the .NET Framework tooling for VS Code is not mature (and likely never will be), and you're going to continue to run into lots of issues like you've just experienced with it.

Comment: Agreed.  Rule #1 that I have learned with VSCode...  If it's not working as intended, check OmniSharp.  It's usually 90% of my pain with VSCode.  I have a love/hate relationship with it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was running into was the namespace `Newtonsoft` could not be found after changing the framework from `net5.0` to `net48`.

The issue was OmniSharp that was giving a false positive.  I restarted VSCode and the issue went away once VSCode loaded with the new framework being used.

Answer (score 0):

.NET supports [cross platform targeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting) which means you can have your SDK style .NET5 project [multi-targets both `net5` and `net48`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-a-target-framework). In future, if the third-party library targets `.NET Core` then you can simply change the `TargetFrameworks` property.

A similar issue has been discussed here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/40304 incase if that helps.